# Cross Threading Controls

Tags: c#, picturebox, multithreading

I'm currently trying to create a timer that will run a chunk of code every few milliseconds. the problem is i want to be able to Modify the position of a picture box that is created on the same thread as the timer, I end up getting the Invoke object error even though its not created on the original thread ?

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Update Timer Thread
    UpdateThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateWindow));
    SleepTime = (int)1000/MaxFps;
    UpdateThread.Start();        
    //.....
}

delegate void SetTextCB(string text);
delegate void SetControl(Control cntrl);

public void TimerThread()
{
    //Controls
    PictureBox TestPicBox;

    //Test TestPicBox
    TestPicBox = new PictureBox();
    TestPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(TestImage.bmp");
    TestPicBox.Top = 20;
    TestPicBox.Left = 20;
    TestPicBox.Width = 64;
    TestPicBox.Height = 64;
    FilePanelControl(TestPicBox);

    while (true)
    {
        //--Sleep
        Thread.Sleep(SleepTime);
        //--FPS
        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") != SystemTime)
        {
            if (blnShowFps) { lblFpsTextsSet(UpdateFps.ToString() + "-FPS"); }
            else { lblFpsTextsSet(""); }
            SystemTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            UpdateFps = 0;
        }
        UpdateFps++;
        //Sleep Time
        SleepTime = (int)1000 / MaxFps;

        //Do UpDate Logic
        TestPicBox.location = new point(10,10);
    }
}

//--Add Control
private void FilePanelControl(Control added)
{
    if (this.FilePanel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetControl d = new SetControl(FilePanelControl);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { added });
    }
    else
    {
        this.FilePanel.Controls.Add(added);
    }
}

//--lblFps.text
private void lblFpsTextsSet(string text)
{
    if (this.lblFPS.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCB d = new SetTextCB(lblFpsTextsSet);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblFPS.Text = text;
    }
}
```

hoping i don't have to invoke every control i declare on this thread as the plan was to make a picture box list, so the user could add picture boxes as needed.

Thanks For the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`) should be used to set `PictureBox.Location`. Control properties must be set on the thread where the control handle was created, that is decided by WinForms, not where the control itself was created.

The reasons are explained in [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx).

Here is more information on [multithreading in Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229730.aspx) that includes an example of using a background thread.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of creating your own thread.

This way, everthying will already be on the UI thread.

Comment: The windows timer is inaccurate and slow, if its set to run at 1ms i only get 64fps although it should be running at 1000 or close to it

Comment: Don't run every millisecond; there's no point.  You should probably aim for about 30 FPS.  In fact, I would recommend running every 100ms.

Comment: I'm not planning on running it that fast but i would like to be able to run it at 60-100fps accurately

Comment: Given that monitors are only 60FPS, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: yes many monitors are locked at 60htz, not all most LCD TVs run at 120 or a "3D" TV runs at 240, I just want to know if it is possible to do it my way, I'm sorry but I'm  not interested in using a normal windows timer, but thank you anyway

Comment: As the errors state, you cannot interact with the UI from a different thread.  UI is not thread-safe.

Comment: Stopwatch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx is based on High resolution timer (where available), you can check that with IsHighResolution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Stopwatch just measures; it doesn't schedule callbacks.